# From enum to dynamic values from a textfile

Tags: java, dynamic, enums

I have real trouble here. I have a lot of Java code containing hundreds of classes and some projects. I have in this code a job enum.

```
public enum Jobtype {

    Teacher,
    Driver,
    Nurse,
    Waiter,
    Businessman,
    Electrican
}
```

This enum is used in tens of places in the code eg. `Job currentjob = Job.Waiter;` etc. Now I want to have dynamic jobs. By reading from a textfile that contain different jobs, the jobs is then added from the textfile into the ArrayList during runtime. That means I cannot have an enum anymore, because the jobs in the enum can be changed (mabey only containing only the jobs "engineer" and "Cook"). So I need to change my code. I was thinking of creating a new class called Job.

```
public class Job{
    
    private String Job = "";

    
    public Job(String Job) {
        
        this.Job= Job;
    }

    public String getJob() {
        return Job;
    }

    public void setJob(String Job) {
        this.Job = Job;
    }

}
```

Then Create a new `arraylist<Job> job = new Arraylist<Job>;` and add new jobs based on input. However, this means if I delete the enum types I will get errors ALL over the code. And there is no way I can change every place in the code. IS there ANY way where I can just use array or any other kind of dynamic code where user can add new jobs during runtime instead of enum without having me change all these places?

For example there are functions like:

```
public void(String name, Jobtype job) {
        
        if (job != Jobtype.Doctor) {
            System.out.print("%s is Not a doctor" + name);  
        } 
    }
```

As you can see these type of function have the enum type
”Jobtype” as argument. If I delete the enum then all function having similar arguments will have an error. That means I need to change the code in many places which is ineffective. I need some type of soultion for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You called your enum `Jobs`; that's a common mistake, it should have been `Job`. Fortunately, any popular IDE (Eclipse, intellij, and netbeans can all do this) can trivially refactor your entire codebase here: Rename it using the 'rename' refactor script and the tool will rename all the code for you, in one go.

Then, you can replace the enum with a class, but keep the 'hardcoded' roles. However, to ensure that `==` style equality continues to function, you **must ensure** that the constructor of `Job` remain **private**.

```
public class Job {
    private final String job;

    private static final Map<String, Job> cache = new HashMap<>();

    private Job(String job) {
        this.job = job;
    }

    public static Job of(String job) {
        return cache.computeIfAbsent(job, j -> new Job(j));
    }

    public static final Job Doctor = of("Doctor");
    // repeat for all your existing enum values.
}
```

At that point, you can still write `Job.Doctor`, and even `Job.Doctor == Job.of("Doctor")` and all will continue to work. You can omit the refactor described at the top of this answer, but then you have a misnamed type.

NB: This class would, eventually, start leaking memory but only if you invent hundreds of thousands of job titles. Be aware that if this is running on a public site someone could be a real clown and write a script, but short of that sort of abuse, it won't be an issue. if it is an issue, a more complicated refactor is probably your only solution.

Comment: You say I should keep my old hard coded jobs. The problem is the jobs can vary, meaning mabey if I have one day enum roles  ”Doctor” and ”Driver” the next day mabey I have ”Nurse” and ”Teacher”. This means that the roles vary all the time. It is not nessesary to have the same old roles every time. The ones that are defined at runtime are the ones that matter. If I keep the hardcoded roles then mabey I dont even need to use them and that means I have roles I don’t even want to be defined at that time. How can go past that?

Comment: Hey, you had the requirement you wanted to change as little of the existing code as possible. I assumed that meant "I have written 'Jobs.Doctor' and the like all over the code base and I don't want to mess with it too much". This solution explains how to accomplish this whilst also making the concept of 'job title' dynamic.

Comment: Yes I understand you mean but what I meant is like this. Imagine you have a code with enum Job and there are some roles inside eg. "Doctor", "Driver", "Nurse", "Teacher" and "lawyer". Now these roles are used is many places in the code. Also these roles are also taken as arguments inside functions and is also returned as arguments etc. Now if I simply remove enum then all of these codes will have errors since they contain these roles. What I is a way to change the roles whenever I want (add/remove) during runtime. This means that I dont want enum but also dont want to change  code all over.

Comment: No, they won't contain errors. That's why I wrote that class precisely as I did. Try it: Write it, compile it, type `Job.Doctor`, it will work, and compile, and compare properly with `==`.

Comment: thanks, one last question. what do you mean by "j -> new Job9j" because this gives me an error.

Comment: @MohammedAbdu typo; it was supposed to read `j -> new Job(j)`, I fixed the answer, apologies.